# adding row 1 min timestamp within the date and time range

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

I have imported the data from CSV and found some missing 1min timestamps in data. I am looking for some solution for handling  those missing time stamps,

I have tried `asfeq('t')` method in order to achieve but it is giving out of range values also.

For time range i have used   `x1=x1.between_time('09:16', '15:30')`

[Image for ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24RI3.png)

Here is the sample data

```
01-04-2020 09:16    2018400
01-04-2020 09:18    2022800
01-04-2020 09:19    2022800
01-04-2020 09:22    2030800
01-04-2020 09:23    2030800
01-04-2020 09:24    2035200
01-04-2020 09:25    2035200
03-04-2020 09:16    2018400
03-04-2020 09:18    2022800
03-04-2020 09:19    2022800
03-04-2020 09:22    2030800
04-04-2020 09:23    2030800
04-04-2020 09:25    2035200
04-04-2020 09:27    2035200
04-04-2020 09:29    2042000
08-04-2020 09:18    2042000
08-04-2020 09:21    2043600
08-04-2020 09:24    2043600
08-04-2020 09:27    2043600
08-04-2020 09:30    2048000
08-04-2020 09:33    2048000
08-04-2020 09:36    2048000
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried `asfeq('t')` method in order to achieve but it is giving out of range values also.

You surely mean `asfreq('t')`. That should do what you want (if I understand it), but we'd need a `DatetimeIndex`, which (judged from the image) your first column isn't. This can be accomplished by `pd.read_csv(…, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but i am looking at different solution, i want to achieve adding a row with time stamp where data is missing. If i am using asfeq('t') method i am getting missing timestamp row added and also ( out of range data which i don't require)

for example if am i require only if i am working on 1 year data with lot of holidays for which the data is not in the preliminary dateset . If i am using asfre method i am able to achieve the solution but the problem is i am also getting  rows for the unwanted dates like holidays and Saturdays and Sundays)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand which dates exactly you consider as _wanted_ and which ones as _unwanted_; you'd have to specify this precisely, not just as _like_.